# How do you get and use a Refresh Token for the Dropbox API (Python 3.x)

Tags: python, python-3.x, access-token, dropbox, dropbox-api

As the title says, I am trying to generate a refresh token, and then I would like to use the refresh token to get short lived Access tokens.

There is a problem though, in that I'm not smart enough to understand the [docs on the dropbox site](https://developers.dropbox.com/oauth-guide), and all the other information I've found hasn't worked for me
([A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67318765/getting-a-new-refresh-token-when-using-one-to-get-an-access-token-dropbox-v2-api), [B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813049/dropbox-api-request-token-not-working-with-python-3), [C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67116516/dropbox-sdk-dotnet-how-to-get-a-refresh-token-and-update-the-access-token)) or is in a language I don't understand.

I have tried out all [three examples from the github page](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/tree/main/example/oauth), as well as user code from other questions on this site.

I haven't got anything to work.

The most I got was

> Error: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: api.dropboxapi.com/oauth2/token

and

> dropbox.rest.RESTSocketError: Error connecting to "api.dropbox.com": [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)

:(

Comment: Version 1.6 of the `dropbox` library is very old; you should use the latest version, currently v11.25.0. You can find an example of processing the OAuth app authorization flow to get and use a refresh token with that here: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/blob/main/example/oauth/commandline-oauth-pkce.py

Comment: @Greg I changed back to the latest version and I tried all the examples out. I couldn't get any of them to work. The most I got was "Error: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://api.dropboxapi.com/oauth2/token". :(

Comment: I recommend posting a new question with the full details of whatever you're currently stuck on.

Comment: @Greg honestly I haven't made any progression. The only things I've done are try more code examples and still none of them have worked.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community I would if I had any code that got me close. :'(
All the code I have tried, I have left a link to the source of.

Comment: there's  NO END-to-END explanation or example  how to get an access token.
The tutorials end up on creating an app, which gives you API key+secret, but that's it.
Where do you create a token?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here is how I did it. I'll try to keep it simple and precise

Replace <APP_KEY> with your dropbox app key in the below Authorization URL

https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<APP_KEY>&token_access_type=offline&response_type=code

Complete the code flow on the Authorization URL. You will receive an **AUTHORIZATION_CODE** at the end.

Go to [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) and create a new POST request with below configuration

- Request URL- https://api.dropboxapi.com/oauth2/token
- Authorization -> Type = Basic Auth -> *Username* = <APP_KEY> , *Password* = <APP_SECRET>
  (Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28529598/18744450) for cURL -u option)
- Body -> Select "x-www-form-urlencoded"

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| code | <AUTHORIZATION_CODE> |
| grant_type | authorization_code |

After you send the request, you will receive JSON payload containing **refresh_token**.

```
{
    "access_token": "sl.****************",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 14400,
    "refresh_token": "*********************",
    "scope": <SCOPES>,
    "uid": "**********",
    "account_id": "***********************"
}
```

In your python application,

```
import dropbox

dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(
            app_key = <APP_KEY>,
            app_secret = <APP_SECRET>,
            oauth2_refresh_token = <REFRESH_TOKEN>
        )
```

Hope this works for you too!

Comment: I got this to work, but do I have to repeat these steps constantly?  Or does that refresh token last for good?  I need to continually log in to dropbox as part of a scheduled job.

Comment: No, you don't need to repeat these steps again. Refresh tokens won't expire until you revoke them. Read [this](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-API-Support-Feedback/Oauth2-refresh-token-question-what-happens-when-the-refresh/td-p/486241) interesting thread from the dropbox forum

Comment: I have not found how to use Postman to create a new POST request, at least without registering. May be something has changed since you answered? Anyway, the snippet of orellabac made the trick.

Comment: I'm getting "code doesn't exist or has expired" no matter what I do. My Access Code is freshly generated.

Comment: Thanks for @Sparrow your answer. I followed your steps and had a refresh token. I was wondering how to use it with requests module for the long-lived authorization? Is it possible to do that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 13):

All methods above work, just want to post a pure python solution, which itself draws reference from the answers above.

1. Find the **APP key** and **App secret** from the [App Console](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps).
2. Run the following snippet (replace `APP_KEY` with the value
   obtained from last step) and complete the process in the
   browser to obtain **Access Code Generated**.

```py
import webbrowser

APP_KEY = '<APP_KEY>'
url = f'https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id={APP_KEY}&' \
      f'response_type=code&token_access_type=offline'

webbrowser.open(url)
```

3. Replace all `APP_KEY`, `APP_SECRET`, and `ACCESS_CODE_GENERATED` with the actual values in the following snippet. Run the snippet.

```py
import base64
import requests
import json

APP_KEY = '<APP_KEY>'
APP_SECRET = '<APP_SECRET>'
ACCESS_CODE_GENERATED = '<ACCESS_CODE_GENERATED>'

BASIC_AUTH = base64.b64encode(f'{APP_KEY}:{APP_SECRET}'.encode())

headers = {
    'Authorization': f"Basic {BASIC_AUTH}",
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}

data = f'code={ACCESS_CODE_GENERATED}&grant_type=authorization_code'

response = requests.post('https://api.dropboxapi.com/oauth2/token',
                         data=data,
                         auth=(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET))
print(json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), indent=2))
```

Comment: As a small correction, for me it worked after writting `f"Basic {BASIC_AUTH.decode()}"`. For some reason, as BASIC_AUTH is a bytes object, it was writting the b'' characters inside the string. Decoding it first removed these characters.

Answer (score 11):

The previous answer worked as a charmed, but if you need something quick to run, you can use this snippet:

```bash
#/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter APP_KEY" 
read APP_KEY

echo -n "Enter APP_SECRET" 
read APP_SECRET
BASIC_AUTH=$(echo -n $APP_KEY:$APP_SECRET | base64)

echo "Navigate to URL and get ACCESS CODE"
echo "https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=$APP_KEY&token_access_type=offline&response_type=code"

echo -n "Return to this script once you have the ACCESS_CODE" 
read DUMMY

echo -n "Enter the ACCESS_CODE" 
read ACCESS_CODE_GENERATED

curl --location --request POST 'https://api.dropboxapi.com/oauth2/token' \
--header "Authorization: Basic $BASIC_AUTH" \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode "code=$ACCESS_CODE_GENERATED" \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=authorization_code'
```